# How Tensor placeholder and Numpy results are different in below code snippet?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, placeholder

Code Snippet:

```
np.random.seed(101)
init =tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(x,feed_dict={x:np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, no_of_features))}))
    print(np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, no_of_features)))
```

Results are:

[[0.5163986  0.57066756 0.02847423 0.17152166]]

[[0.68527698 0.83389686 0.30696622 0.89361308]]

What I could do to get same results in both statements

Comment: Each time you call `np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, no_of_features))` you will get a new random array. Either call it only once and save its result (i.e. `a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, no_of_features)); print(sess.run(x,feed_dict={x:a})); print(a)`) or reset the seed before each call to get always the same result.

Comment: Here, np.random.seed(101) doesn't handle to get same result, across the calls of same random function? Just like calling same random function  for n times?

Comment: `np.random.seed` will only initialize the random number generator to a specific state. It ensures that the results you get are repeatable, e.g. if you do `np.random.seed(101); print(np.random.rand()); print(np.random.rand()); print(np.random.rand())` you will get three different numbers, but they will always be the same three different numbers each time you run it.

Comment: Thank You@jdehesa